# How to convert a string into dictionary in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Beginning with a string like:

```
S='a=65 b=66 c=67'
```

How would you create an output a dict like `{'a':'65','b':'66','c':'67'}`

Attempt:

```
S='a=65 b=66 c=67'
L=s.split(' ')
D=dict()
A=''
i=0
While i<Len(L):
    A=L[i].split('=')
    D[a[i]]=a[i+1]
    i+2

print (D)
```

> Error on line 8  indexerror list index out of range

Answer (score 9):

Let's use comprehension and split:

```
dict(i.split('=') for i in S.split())
```

Output:

```
{'a': '65', 'b': '66', 'c': '67'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using index i to iterate over L, but you use (i+1) to access A, this will lead to the problem. A might not have the size of Len(L)